# After upgrading to 20.10

Tags: upgrade

Something went wrong with the nvidia driver and now I get 'oh no something has gone wrong'

How to recover or get back to 20.04 ?

Comment: How can we know what backup strategy you've put in place?  `apt`, `dpkg` & packaging tools are intended to be used to upgrade systems (not downgrade) so you can either restore a backup, or re-install (without format though if you've used newer features and changed there can be complications on a application basis)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with my NVIDIA card when upgraded to 20.10. I was informed that before I should disable the proprietary drivers. I tryed to uninstall o remove the drivers but post installation script sent a message the error. So I rebooted and selected in the grub option Recovery and selected a kernel older than the one I was using, there I disabled the propietary (privative) driver and rebooted normally. I was immediately recognized by my monitor without problems.
Sorry by my English language is not my native longe.

Comment: Note:
Not sure if this is the correct way of approaching things but it worked for me :)